# Callback from whatsapp after sharing done

Tags: android, whatsapp, android-sharing

I want to share image to whatsapp from my app, but after successful sharing done on whatsapp I want to call a webservice in my application, can anyone please help me in achieving this task...

Comment: You can't get callback from whatsapp as they don't have library or sdk for developers

Comment: @reena can you help me out in this like is there any other way to achieve this ? I mean I want to hit webservice after sharing done...

Answer (score 5):

Varun.. I have the solution for you, With the help of onActivityResult you can get a callback after sharing anything on WhatsApp. Please use following steps
 1. Start your intent to receive result from another app

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
  sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
  sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
  startActivityForResult(sendIntent,1); //1 is request code
```

2.Override onActivityResult in your activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),"onActivityResult..:",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Got Callback yeppeee...:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this may solve your problem, Happy coding.

Comment: @AtefHares, Its working fine with Result_Ok and Cancelled

Comment: in case of whatsapp we are getting Result_OK for successfull shared , but Gmail/Skype return's canceled code for success/failure of shared message. please let me know if you have any suggestion , I am too facing this problem..any solution

Comment: Can we get the contact to whom the data was sent in whatsapp?

Comment: @SamudraGanguly - I guess you can check for Intent data when we get the callback after sharing